# Copiar archivo segun fecha mediande consola

Tags: cmd, batch

Tengo un listado de archivos `.rar` en una unidad de red los cuales se generan automáticamente uno por día.

Lo que intento hacer es generar un `.bat` que vaya a esa unidad de red y copie el archivo más reciente según la fecha de **modificación** o de **creación** (con la que trabaje mejor). Sólo debe ser el archivo más reciente.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
@echo off
echo ============INICIANDO PROCESO DE COPIADO=============
echo ......=ACEDIENDO A LA CARPETA DE LOS ARCHIVOS=.......
W:
echo .....................................................
echo ==============EMPEZANDO COPIA DE ARCHIVO=============
set fecha=%date%
xcopy "W:\UnidadDeRed\*.rar" /d:%fecha% "C:\DestinoArchivo\*.rar"

echo .............=COPIA DE ARCHIVO TERMINADA=............
echo =====================================================
pause
```

En el código estoy declarando `fecha` y le doy un valor mediante el operador `date` así obtengo la fecha actual, luego uso la varible `fecha` en el modificador `/d:` de la instrucción `xcopy`. El modificador sirve para copiar archivos cambiados durante o después de la fecha especificada.

Así es cómo está actualmente, pero me sale el siguiente error:
[image: Error de parametro no valido]

El formato de fecha de mi equipo es ese y el de los archivos también es así:
[image: Formato de fecha igual en todos lados]

Si le quito el modificador empieza a copiar todos los archivos lo cual no quiero, pero entonces:

¿Por qué ese error?¿Cómo se usa ese modificador?
¿Será porque los archivos tienen hora?¿Alguna otra forma?

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Los parametros no están en orden correcto debes seguir este orden:

```
xcopy source [destination] [/a] [/b] [/c] [/d [:date]] [/e] [/f] [/g] [/h]
[/i] [/j] [/k] [/l] [/m] [/n] [/o] [/p] [/q] [/r] [/s] [/t] [/u] [/v] [/w]
[/x] [/y] [/-y] [/z]
```

Como puedes observar primero van el origen y destino y despues las flags, yo puse algunas:

- /a para copiar un archivo
- /i para evitar el prompt de si es un archivo o directorio
- /d para la fecha

Yo hice pruebas en **Windows 10** y funcionó

Con este código:

```
@echo off
echo ============INICIANDO PROCESO DE COPIADO=============
echo ......=ACEDIENDO A LA CARPETA DE LOS ARCHIVOS=.......
W:
echo .....................................................
echo ==============EMPEZANDO COPIA DE ARCHIVO=============
set fecha=%date%
xcopy "W:\UnidadDeRed\*.rar" "C:\DestinoArchivo\*.rar" /a /i /d:%fecha%

echo .............=COPIA DE ARCHIVO TERMINADA=............
echo =====================================================

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

En vez de hacer eso, puedes obtener el nombre del archivo más reciente y pasárselo al `xcopy` como parámetro. Esto te debería funcionar:

```
@echo off
echo ============INICIANDO PROCESO DE COPIADO=============
echo ......=ACCEDIENDO A LA CARPETA DE LOS ARCHIVOS=......
echo .....................................................
echo ==============EMPEZANDO COPIA DE ARCHIVO=============
echo.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir W:\UnidadDeRed\*.rar /b /a-d /od') do set ultimo=%%a
xcopy "W:\UnidadDeRed\%ultimo%" "C:\DestinoArchivo"
echo.
echo .............=COPIA DE ARCHIVO TERMINADA=............
echo =====================================================
pause
```

Nota que si el archivo existe, te pedirá confirmación para sobreescribir. Si le dejas el parámetro `/D` sin ninguna fecha, sólo copiará si la fecha es más reciente.

**Opción 2:**

Si en la carpeta origen sólo se van agregando estos backups y tú simplemente los vas replicando en el destino, podrías usar algo tan sencillo como:

`xcopy "W:\UnidadDeRed\*.rar" /D "C:\DestinoArchivo"`

Con esto ya lograrías tu cometido, porque no va a volver a copiar ningún archivo que ya exista y tenga la misma fecha.

*PS: Nota que corregí el error en el segundo `echo`.* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ocupaba hacer algo parecido y no logre hacer funcionar sus propuestas, pero modificando un poco sus aportaciones lo hice funcionar. A continuación les incluyo el codigo que probé y me funcionó:

```
@echo off
echo ==============EMPEZANDO COPIA DE ARCHIVO=============

set fecha=%date%

for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set "fecha=%%b-%%a-%%c"

xcopy "*.txt" "C:\Pruebas\" /y /i /d:%fecha%

echo .............=COPIA DE ARCHIVO TERMINADA=............
echo =====================================================
```

Este codigo ya incluye la instruccion con la fecha tal como la necesita el comando `xcopy`.

Espero les sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Si miras la ayuda del comando `xcopy` te encontrarás con que el formato de fecha que tienes que pasar no corresponde con el de los ficheros ni con el dl sistema. El formato es `/D:m-d-y`, en ese orden y con guiones, no puntos.

Tienes la opción de procesar el valor de la fecha para adaptarlo al formato de `xcopy`

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ("%date%") do set "fecha=%%b-%%a-%%c"
```

O puedes usar `robocopy` indicando que solo quieres ficheros con una antiguedad máxima de un día

```
robocopy "W:\UnidadDeRed" "C:\DestinoArchivo" *.rar /maxage:1
```